# How to sort associative array with specified sequence of values?

Tags: php

I want to sort associative array with specified sequence of values

```
$arr=array(array("company"=>"A", "revenue_range"=>"10-100M"),
      array("company"=>"B", "revenue_range"=>"0-10M"),
      array("company"=>"C", "revenue_range"=>"10-100M"),
      array("company"=>"D", "revenue_range"=>"100M-1B"),
      array("company"=>"E", "revenue_range"=>">1B"),
     array( "company"=>"F", "revenue_range"=>"0-10M")
```

);

Result:-

```
$arr=array(array("company"=>"B", "revenue_range"=>"0-10M"),
       array( "company"=>"F", "revenue_range"=>"0-10M"),
      array("company"=>"A", "revenue_range"=>"10-100M"),
      array("company"=>"C", "revenue_range"=>"10-100M"),
      array("company"=>"D", "revenue_range"=>"100M-1B"),
      array("company"=>"E", "revenue_range"=>">1B"));
```

Comment: This is not a valid PHP array.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $arr = array( 
        array("company"=>"A", "revenue_range"=>"100 - 250M"), 
        array("company"=>"B", "revenue_range"=>"10 - 50M"), 
        array("company"=>"C", "revenue_range"=>"500M - 1B"), 
        array("company"=>"D", "revenue_range"=>"50 - 100M"), 
        array("company"=>"E", "revenue_range"=>">1B"), 
        array("company"=>"F", "revenue_range"=>"1 - 10M"), 
        array("company"=>"G", "revenue_range"=>"0 - 1M") 
        ); 
    $order= array("0 - 1M", "1 - 10M", "10 - 50M", "50 - 100M", "100 - 250M", "250 - 500M", "500M - 1B", ">1B");
    $order_by=array_flip($order);
    usort($arr, function($a, $b) use($order_by) {
        return $order_by[$a["revenue_range"]] - $order_by[$b["revenue_range"]];
    });
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Yes this works fine i have another array is below $arr = [
  array("company"=>"A", "revenue_range"=>"100 - 250M"),
  array("company"=>"B", "revenue_range"=>"10 - 50M"),
  array("company"=>"C", "revenue_range"=>"500M - 1B"),
  array("company"=>"D", "revenue_range"=>"50 - 100M"),
  array("company"=>"E", "revenue_range"=>">1B"),
  array("company"=>"F", "revenue_range"=>"1 - 10M"),
  array("company"=>"F", "revenue_range"=>"0 - 1M")
];

Comment: @MagikVishal Updated the code, that should work with your second scenario.

Comment: whoever down-voted the answer, please provide an explanation in the comment section, as I would like to learn the reason why. I have triple checked it to ensure that it fulfils the requirement. If there is a valid reason such as the use of bad practice then one can one learn from it if info is provided. It is really upsetting when people down vote without providing a reason. It takes effort to write code. I am perfectly happy to stand corrected if there is a flaw but not when I am left clueless of why my answer was down voted.

Comment: @MagikVishal please confirm if the code works for you, if so would appreciate if you accept my answer or vote up, if it doesn't work feedback would be appreciate too.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and pass a comparison function that assigns the revenue_range strings numeric values (i.e. if "0-10M" is 1 and "10-100M" is 2, ... and ">1B" is 5, then you end up with  ">1B" > "0-10M").